# How to insert page number starting from custom index in Pages 5.6.1

Tags: macos, pages

I am having a project work which is split up as 10 different documents (each one is assumed to be a chapter). The first document has 12 pages, and I inserted page numbers and things are fine till this line.

Now I want to start the page number from 13 on the next document (Say chapter 2). I do not see any naked options which can do this.

What could be the possible workaround?

Answer (score 1):

This pages help document has the answer for this question. Please refer https://help.apple.com/pages/mac/5.6/index.html?localePath=en.lproj#/tan7248753e

Comment: Please summarise the method here in case the URL changes or vanishes in future.

Comment: Sure I will do that